# Use of slip rings and its working in a AC generator

Tags: electromagnetism, electronics, electrical-engineering

What is the use of [slip rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slip_ring) in an AC generator and its working? What would happen if there was no slip rings?

Answer (score 1):

Slip rings provide an electrical connection to the spinning coils in the rotor.  Without slip rings electric current induced in the coils of the rotor couldn't be delivered to the external load.  I suppose you could just hardwire a connection the to the rotor but it wouldn't take more than a few revolutions before connection wires would be hopelessly tangled and wrapped around the spiny bits.

An alternative to using slip rings would be using a split ring like in a brushed DC motor.  This has the effect of producing output current that is full wave rectified rather than AC.

Comment: But then its not going to be an AC generator now is it?

Answer (score 0):

To provide a varying strength to the magnetic field (either induced by the rotating stator field, or introduced by an external resistance/current) of the rotor, and to allow that magnetic field to rotate, by causing current to flow through its windings.  No rotor windings, typically no need for slip rings, unless you're trying to gather physical parameters of the rotor via instrumentation (thermocouples, strain gauges, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that the generator in your car uses a rotating magnet field powered by a (small) constant current which is supplied through the slip rings.  The AC output from fixed coils is rectified by heavy duty diodes and fed into the car's DC system.